# cakephp allow dot in params passed to an action

Tags: php, .htaccess, cakephp

I have a function which accepts a bunch of params in the URL. One of the parameters however is an operating system version. So it has the format like: 5.6.02

This seems to not be allowed in cakephp and thus it breaks my function. I have no control over what is passed to the action because it comes from another source, otherwise I guess I could replace the dots with underscores or something.

So my question is, how can I allow this particular function to accept GET parameters even when they contain dots? Thanks

Comment: What version of Cake are you using?

Comment: If you need to pass non ascii characters, use query strings :) That allows all and any characters.

Comment: I'm using version 2 Greg. Mark, the issue is that I have no control over what gets sent to my function. It's coming from an outside source, so there will be a dot in it no matter what. Any ideas?

Comment: Your best bet would be using your webserver's native URL rewriting and transforming the incoming URI into querystring, as @mark mentioned they accept everything.

Alternatively you may try creating a Dispatch Filter and do a redirect with querystrings

https://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/development/dispatch-filters.html